# Difference between Mapping and Collections C# and what to use

Tags: c#, sql, object, collections, dictionary

***ORGINAL SPEAL***

Ok so im kind of in a pickle and maybe I can get some clarification and advice here. Im not much familiar with C# but I have done something similar in a Groovy/Grails web application.

So my issue. I have two objects. One is a Shipper(holds basic info on a shipping company). The other is a Vehicle object(Holds information about shipping vehicles). Now a Shipper can have numbers types of shipping vehicles. These are going to be populated in a local sql database in visual studio 2010. I was going to put all this information into one shipper object and one shipper table. Instead I am going the route of making the two different objects. My issue is bringing them back together from the db and linking them into one joined object. What I have done in a Groovy/Grails web application (with help) was Map two objects, A user and a role which came from 2 different tables, together off an id (I'm don't know if I fully understand this but I'm working with it - There was a lot of hand holding)

So in C#. I was looking at mapping and I'm not sure if this is needed or how to go about it. Taking Shipper + Vehicle and making a Shipper/Vehicle object. My lack of understanding in the subject I think makes these seem really trivial.

Or would this be something that I would need an collection for? Making a collection of these two objects.

So maybe a clarification on the two when it comes to C# or at least a Simplified explanation of the two and maybe some basic implementations of each.

I don't need anything too extensive. Im having some crazy coders block on this one for some reason (Might be the copious amounts of red bull and coffee).

Again I lack a lot of knowledge on these datatypes and c# in general.

Ill be monitoring this and updating as I personally progress or more questions/flaming arise. I just need opinions and help to get past this blocker.

***EDIT/NEW SPEAL***

Ok. So since I don't even know where to start. And given the information above.

I do not understand the difference between Collections and Mapping in C#(or any language at that matter) even after looking up the two. They seem similar to me.

so NEW QUESTION: In this situation, would you use a Map or a Collection. A "Why" would be nice but not needed I guess if thats asking too much.

If I can get that answered then I will be happen and try to go figure it out. I just don't wanna go down a rabbit hole that went the wrong way. I understand the hate of asking a question without showing what iv done. But I have not got that far because of this underlying question. Sorry for the "ignorance" but I would really like to understand which path to at least start down in this situation. I wasn't asking for "hey code this for me". Examples would surely help but a decent explanation would of been nice at least. But I guess ill just ask a yes/no, do this/that question and Ill take it from there.

-Sorry?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Sorry ... are you just asking what ORM to use? ...

Comment: you should be more specific in your question. I don't understand what you mean by Map. Which map data structure are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of learning my C#, so I don't understand what you mean by the Map datastructure. Here's a very informative site regarding collections that will tell you about how to use each datastructure:

http://csharp.net-informations.com/collection/csharp-collection-tutorial.htm

If I knew what you mean by Map, I might be able to help you further.